# How to extract all text under the same tag using XPath?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-crawler, text-extraction

```
<span rel="v:addr">
<span property="v:region">
  <a href="https://tabelog.com/en/tokyo/">
    123
  </a>
</span>
<span property="v:locality">
  <a href="https://tabelog.com/en/tokyo/A1317/A131710/rstLst/">
    456
  </a>
    <a href="https://tabelog.com/en/rstLst/">
      789
    </a>
  10
</span>
<span property="v:street-address">

</span>
</span>
```

I want to extract the text inside the span tag without any space and make it as a one single string at the end.

I want this result:

```
12345678910
```

This is my code below:

```
'AddressLocalityJap':"".join(response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="anchor-rd-detail"]/section[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/p[2]/span/span[2]//text()').extract())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all spans by `//span/span`. And get text in each span use `text_content()`. And substitute all whitespace characters use regex.

```
import re
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(html_source)

span = tree.xpath("//span/span", smart_strings=0)

text = ''.join([re.sub(r"\s+", '', item.text_content()) for item in span])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pure XPath 1.0 solution

This XPath,

```
translate(string(normalize-space()), ' ', '')
```

will return

```
12345678910
```

for your HTML, as requested.